# calculus new methods functional equationI

Tags: calculus

hi I would like to find a $F(x)$ so that

> $$
> F(x-i)-F(x+i)=\frac{1}{x}.$$

Comment: Is $i$ an integer or the imaginary unit?

Comment: is i complex number

Comment: By the way, where did this problem come from?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution

> $$F(x) = \frac{i}{2} \psi \left( \frac{ 1+ix }{2}  \right),\quad \quad i=\sqrt{-1}, $$

where $\psi(x)$ is the [digamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function).

Comment: well done could you give how do you get it thanks

Comment: @capea: I'll try to do this later.